# I created a class for the QPushButton widget in PyQt5, but it doesn't show after I create an instance of it

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanted to try and see if I could create a class for the QPushButton widget in PyQt5 to save some lines. But once I create to create an instance of the `Button` class, it doesn't appear anywhere on the `win` instance of the `Window` class.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Nested Layouts")
        self.resize(800, 200)
        self.show()
    class Button(QPushButton):
        def __init__(self, btn_parent, btn_text, btn_width, btn_height, btn_xCor, btn_yCor):
            super().__init__()
            self.btn_parent = btn_parent
            self.btn_text = btn_text
            self.btn_width = btn_width
            self.btn_height = btn_height
            self.btn_xCor = btn_xCor
            self.btn_yCor = btn_yCor
            self.setText(self.btn_text)
            self.resize(btn_width, btn_height)
            self.move(btn_xCor, btn_yCor)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
button = Window.Button(btn_parent=win, btn_text="This won't work", btn_width=10, btn_height=10, btn_xCor=10, btn_yCor=10)
app.exec()
```

I even tried to make it like this, but the results are the same:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Nested Layouts")
        self.resize(800, 200)
        self.show()
class Button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, btn_parent, btn_text, btn_width, btn_height, btn_xCor, btn_yCor):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn_parent = btn_parent
        self.btn_text = btn_text
        self.btn_width = btn_width
        self.btn_height = btn_height
        self.btn_xCor = btn_xCor
        self.btn_yCor = btn_yCor
        self.setText(self.btn_text)
        self.resize(btn_width, btn_height)
        self.move(btn_xCor, btn_yCor)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
button = Button(btn_parent=win, btn_text="This won't work", btn_width=10, btn_height=10, btn_xCor=10, btn_yCor=10)
app.exec()
```

Keep in mind that I'm kind of new to OOP(and Python and programming in general), so I might have a misunderstanding about how OOP works.

How can I fix this code so that the `button` shows on the `win` instance?

Comment: Do not use nested classes. You could change the init of the button to `super().__init__(btn_parent)` and add `self.show()`, because child widgets created *after* the parent has been shown are not automatically displayed unless `show()` or `setVisible(True)` is explicitly called. The reality, though, is that you should properly learn how to use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: Adding on top of @musicamante, You need to create an object of Button inside your window, which is right now acting as Central Widget and then make it visible. 
Learning a bit about layout manager will really help here.